# Apache to nginx - htaccess doesn't work, nor does trying to convert

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

I'm trying to use an internal framework that typically runs on Apache on nginx.  I've been having no luck converting the htaccess.

I've tried http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/ with no avail.  I then went through to do it myself (came up with different rules) and that doesn't work either.  Here's what I currently have:

```
            index index.php;

            location / {
                    if ( !-e $request_filename ) {
                            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
                            break;
                    }
                    rewrite ^/$ /? last;
            }

            location ~ ^/(assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|license.txt) {

            }

             location ~ \.php$ {
              fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
              fastcgi_index index.php;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              include fastcgi_params;
             }
```

The htaccess I'm trying to convert is:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|license.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L]
```

Would anyone happen to know what's wrong or what I should do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never use an if in an Nginx config. Try this-

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

The rest of it is not rewriting certain files so that long ugly regex location block isn't needed.